# javascript: json response is ok. working with var is wrong

Tags: javascript, android, json, cordova

Here is the situation. I have an application in phonegap/jquerymobile. I want to change the page according to the json data.

When a user starts the app but the current version is not the latest version it needs to change content. This is a fragment of code from the start.html page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var versionValue = ServerSettings.versionCheck();
if(versionValue == true){   
    $("#loginPage").removeClass("hidden");
            $("#updatePage").addClass("hidden");    
}
else{
            $("#loginPage").addClass("hidden");
            $("#updatePage").removeClass("hidden");
}
</script>
```

The function ServerSettings.versionCheck() is below.

```
versionCheck : function() {
        var localAppVersion = 0.8;
        var response = false;
        $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "http://xxx/service/version.php",
                success: function(jsonData) {
                    var currentAppVersion = jsonData.version;
                        if(localAppVersion == currentAppVersion){
                            response = true;
                        }
                        else{
                            response = false;
                        }
                }                       
        });
                    return response;
    }
```

I have verified the response of the json call with a toast. It does get correct response.(version: 0.9) I am pretty sure i make the most dumbest mistake ever but i cannot seem to find it.

Comment: so which variable is giving the incorrect value?

Comment: ServerSettings.versionCheck() is always undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to you trying to access a value that has not been returned yet from the server as your are using asynchronus.

You could refactor you version check to take a callback argument like so.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

     var localAppVersion = 0.8,
         versionValue =false;
     var versionValue = ServerSettings.versionCheck(function(jsonData){

        var currentAppVersion = jsonData.version;
                    if(localAppVersion == currentAppVersion){
                        versionValue = true;
                    }
                    else{
                        versionValue = false;
                    }

        if(versionValue == true){   
           $("#loginPage").removeClass("hidden");
           $("#updatePage").addClass("hidden");    
        }else{
           $("#loginPage").addClass("hidden");
           $("#updatePage").removeClass("hidden");
     }
   });
```

```
versionCheck : function(callback) {
    var localAppVersion = 0.8;
    var response = false;
    $.ajax({
            async: "false",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "http://xxx/service/version.php",
            success: callback                
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to be synchronous, but the config parameter is evaluating to true because it's a string

```
async: "false"
```

Change it to `async: false`, but I'd recommend to switch to asynchronous to avoid blocking the UI.

Also your success callback doesn't return to the outer method, so you'll always get undefined.

```
versionCheck : function() {
    var localAppVersion = 0.8;
    var response = false;
    $.ajax({
            // WARNING: I don't recommend setting this to false in production code
            // While the browser is waiting for the response the page/browser will not respond!!
            async: false,
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "http://xxx/service/version.php",
            success: function(jsonData) {
                var currentAppVersion = jsonData.version;
                response = localAppVersion == currentAppVersion;
            }                       
    });
    return response;
}
```

To make it asynchronous (**Recommended approach**)

```
versionCheck : function(checkCompleteCallback) {
    var localAppVersion = 0.8;
    $.ajax({
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "http://xxx/service/version.php",
            success: function(jsonData) {
                var currentAppVersion = jsonData.version;
                checkCompleteCallback(localAppVersion == currentAppVersion);
            }
    });
}

// Now the check accepts a callback function that executes when the request completes without blocking the UI
ServerSettings.versionCheck(function(versionValue) {
    if(versionValue){   
        $("#loginPage").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#updatePage").addClass("hidden");    
    }
    else {
        $("#loginPage").addClass("hidden");
        $("#updatePage").removeClass("hidden");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax works asynchronously, so when you do the check the response actually is not arrived yet. Put the logic that depends from that value inside the ajax callback.

```
versionCheck : function() {
    var localAppVersion = 0.8;
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "http://xxx/service/version.php",
            success: function(jsonData) {
                var currentAppVersion = jsonData.version;

                if(localAppVersion == currentAppVersion){   
                    $("#loginPage").removeClass("hidden");
                    $("#updatePage").addClass("hidden");    
                }
                else {
                    $("#loginPage").addClass("hidden");
                    $("#updatePage").removeClass("hidden");
                }
            }                       
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Version check is an asynchronous call. So, it will not return true or false. Your `versionValue` will not be true or false. It is better use promises for asynchronous calls.

Change your versionCheck function like this

```
 versionCheck : function() {
            var localAppVersion = 0.8;
            var response = false;
            $.ajax({
                    async: "false",
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "http://xxx/service/version.php",
                    success: function(jsonData) {
                        var currentAppVersion = jsonData.version;
                            if(localAppVersion == currentAppVersion){
                                return true;
                            }
                            else{
                                return false;
                            }
                    }                       
            }).done(function(){
                 if(versionValue == true){   
                    $("#loginPage").removeClass("hidden");
                    $("#updatePage").addClass("hidden");    
                 }
                else{
                     $("#loginPage").addClass("hidden");
                     $("#updatePage").removeClass("hidden");
               }    
           });
        }
```

`jQuery.promise` is available in version > 1.6